# implement a trait for Vec<T> for various numeric T's

Tags: rust

I want to have a trait `TopK` as follows:

```rust
pub trait TopK{
    pub fn top_k(&self, k : size) -> Result<Vec<usize>, io::Error>;
}
```

I would like to implement `TopK` on `Vec<T>` such that the behaviour would depend upon `T`. I have one implementation over all non-float numbers and another one over all float numbers.

Therefore I would like to have something as below:

```rust
impl<T> TopK for Vec<T> where T : num_traits::PrimInt + Copy {
//Implementation where T is any non-floating point number
}

impl<T> TopK for Vec<T> where T : num_traits::Float + Copy{
 //Implementation where T is any floating point number
}
```

This is because floats are only partially ordered and so for floats, I have to make a new struct for all non-NaN floating point numbers and use them inside a binary-heap for TopK computation.

However, trying to do this produces conflicting definition error. What is the design pattern to be followed for this problem ?

Comment: You can implement the trait for each type using a macro: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f25ad85d012fdee0433ac2ec2e5715a2

Comment: Thank you. That works. However, I find it a little surprising that Rust does not have the concept of specialization in template programming as C++ has. In C++ I could have done it trivially for various `T` in `Vec<T>`.  I will try to look into literature on why this difference exists. Thank you again.

Comment: Rust has an [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) for specialization. It is taking a long time to stabilise because Rust has committed to provide safety and coherence guarantees that the developers of C++ are not limited by.